# How to disable automatic sheet renameing for linked sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet, google-forms

I have lots of sheets (tabs) which are reading data from a single tab called Tab_A. For some reason, I've created a google form and linked it to a sheet tab which is automatically called "Responses".

I need to renamed it to Tab_A and then all other sheets will be linked to the new " Tab_A" and rename the old one to "Tab_A_OLD". However, when I rename the old one to Tab_A_Old, the name in all formulas in all other sheets will be updated to "Tab_A_OLD" which means they are still linked the the old one rather than to the new one which is populated with a google form.

One solution of course is to update and rename all formulas in all other tabs and change "Tab_A_OLD" to Tab_A" which is very very time and effort consuming.

Another solution in my mind is to do a "Replace all" and replace all "Tab_A_OLD" with "Tab_A" in every sheets (TAB). Of course I didn't find such an option in google sheet !!

Is there any solution to do this in a simple way?

Thanks

Comment: When you say functions in  *"rename all functions"*, do you mean formulas?

Answer (score 0):

I found a very simple solution:

Install a google sheet add on called [Advanced Find and Replace](https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/advanced_find_and_replace/460077608560), It does all the task. I could replace not even in a single tab, but also in whole sheet's tabs.